# Can you check if a user is viewing a webpage using Electron?

Tags: javascript, npm, electron

Let's say I want to build a simple Electron app that alerts the user when he reaches [example.com](https://example.com)

Would this be possible? And if so, how would I detect if the user is viewing a certain webpage?

Comment: You can query the UserAgent. Most Electron apps will have "electron" in it:
Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) electron/1.0.0 Chrome/53.0.2785.113 Electron/1.4.3 Safari/537.36

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Electron has the [`did-navigate`](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/api/web-contents#event-did-navigate) event which is fired when a page is redirected inside a `BrowserWindow`.

Referring to the above post I think,

```
const { BrowserWindow, dialog } = require('electron')
const win = new BrowserWindow({ width: 800, height: 600 })

win.webContents.on('did-navigate', (event, url, httpResponseCode, httpStatusText) => {
    if(url == "example.com") {
        dialog.showMessageBox({ type: "info", message: `You visited ${url}` });
        //dialog docs at https://www.electronjs.org/docs/api/dialog#dialogshowmessageboxbrowserwindow-options
    }  
})
```